# Bash - how to get a download url form the official plugin wordpress page?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, wget

I'm trying to get the download link of wordpress' plugins via bash script directly from its official age.

For instance, the akismet plugin at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet/

In the HTML source code we can easily recognize where the link for download is:

```
<div class="col-3">
    <p class="button">
        <a href='http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.2.5.3.zip'>
            Download Version 2.5.3
        </a>
    </p>
```

I noticed that the words "Download Version" only appear once in the entire file, just after the download link that we want to get.

Let's say I do not know what is the download link. The question is how can filter the html code in order to get the download link (so later I can use it with wget or curl). All I know is the plugin page url. How do I filter the html code in order to extract the download link.

Thank you.

Comment: "The question is how I do this in bash so I can use in a script." , do what ? download the file ?

Comment: I can download the file once I get the download link. So, I first need to get this link. To download I'll use wget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nadav@shesek:~$ curl -s https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet/ | egrep -o "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/[^']+"
https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.2.5.3.zip


nadav@shesek:~$ wget `curl -s https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet/ | egrep -o "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/[^']+"`
--2011-08-20 16:43:33--  https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.2.5.3.zip
Resolving downloads.wordpress.org... 72.233.56.138, 72.233.56.139
Connecting to downloads.wordpress.org|72.233.56.138|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 27714 (27K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `akismet.2.5.3.zip'

100%[============================================================================================================================================================>] 27,714      39.9K/s   in 0.7s    

2011-08-20 16:43:35 (39.9 KB/s) - `akismet.2.5.3.zip' saved [27714/27714]
```

Notice the `-o` switch for grep, that makes it output the matched part only instead of the entire line.

Comment: Say I do not know what is the download link. All I know is the plugin page url. How do I filter the html code in order to extract the download link.

Comment: That's exactly what this does. Take a closer look at it.

Comment: Indeed it does. Smart and sharp.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following regex:

```
href=['"](.*?)['"]>\s*Download Version [0-9.]+
```

Comment: Any idea how I can put this into sed?